# Twilio API - How to hang up all active calls using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, twilio, twilio-api

I'm looking for help in hanging up all calls regardless of status, using C# and the Twilio API. Something like a no nonsense 'Kill Switch'.

I saw this code written in python and wondered if anyone had any examples in C# I could look at?

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
from twilio.rest.resources import Call

ACCOUNT_SID = "YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID"
AUTH_TOKEN = "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN"
client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)
calls = client.calls.list(status=Call.IN_PROGRESS)

for c in calls:
c.hangup()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
// Install the C# / .NET helper library from twilio.com/docs/csharp/install

using System;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;


class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/console
        const string accountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        const string authToken = "your_auth_token";

        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var call = CallResource.Update(
            status: CallResource.UpdateStatusEnum.Completed,
            pathSid: "CAe1644a7eed5088b159577c5802d8be38"
        );

        Console.WriteLine(call.To);
    }
}
```

You can wrap the `CallResource.Update(...)` method in a for loop and pass a list of active calls as a parameter.

You can find more information here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress-in-csharp#hanging-up-a-call-in-progress

Comment: Thanks Tim. Yes, I had the API reference guide up. I noted though, that in some cases, other languages like python seem to have more available options than C#. It led me to wonder if there was a C# equivalent of the .hangup call. I'm new to C# (like this week) and I don't have a great deal of experience in coding anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this. Not elegant in the least, but it works:

```
private void KillSwitch(string accountSid, string authToken)
    {
        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
        var callsInProgress = CallResource.Read(status: CallResource.StatusEnum.InProgress);
        var callsQueued = CallResource.Read(status: CallResource.StatusEnum.Queued);
        var callsRinging = CallResource.Read(status: CallResource.StatusEnum.Ringing);
        foreach (var call in callsQueued)
        {
            CallResource.Update(status: CallResource.UpdateStatusEnum.Completed, pathSid: call.Sid);
        }
        foreach (var call in callsInProgress)
        {
            CallResource.Update(status: CallResource.UpdateStatusEnum.Completed, pathSid: call.Sid);
        }
        foreach (var call in callsRinging)
        {
            CallResource.Update(status: CallResource.UpdateStatusEnum.Completed, pathSid: call.Sid);
        }
    }
```